# Upload, process and export CSV without Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, upload, export-to-csv

I am building a very simple web tool where user can upload a CSV file, which is then processed and the result CSV can be immediately downloaded.

The upload form:

```
<%= form_tag '/upload', multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :csv %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Import CSV' %>
<% end %>
```

The upload and download actions:

```
def upload
  original_csv = params[:csv]
  p original_csv.path # /var/folders/71/chp2vrc92_19b3jt2fcwhvp80000gn/T/RackMultipart20181025-11469-25guh5.csv
  redirect_to result_path(file_path: original_csv.path)
end

def result
  p params[:file_path] # /var/folders/71/chp2vrc92_19b3jt2fcwhvp80000gn/T/RackMultipart20181025-11469-25guh5.csv
  output_csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    CSV.foreach(params[:file_path], headers: true) do |row|
      #############################################
      # "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen"  #
      # exception is thrown                       #
      #############################################

      # each row data is being processed here
      csv << row
    end
  end

  # Download the file into user's computer
  send_data output_csv
end
```

As you can see from the comments, this method doesn't work because the temp file path no longer exists in `result` action. How can I go about this without touching db at all.

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files are stored as temp files by the application. That means once the request has ended the temp file is automatically deleted. Therefore it doesn't exist anymore when the next page is requested.

One option would be to copy the file by yourself to another location and make it a "real" file in the file system that isn't deleted automatically anymore. But that has downsides too: Now you are responsible to manage and delete these files by yourself too. That means you need to generate unique files names and pass them to the next request and you need to ensure that the file is deleted after it was downloaded otherwise these files would slowly consume all space on your server's disk. Furthermore, this doesn't scale to multiple servers and will only work for small applications running on one server.

A better option might be to just do the upload, the processing and the download in one request, without any redirect. As long as the processing can be done in a reasonable time and in memory this might be a good option to avoid complexity.

```
def upload
  original_csv = params[:csv]

  output_csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    CSV.foreach(original_csv.path, headers: true) do |row|
      # process data
      csv << row
    end
  end

  send_data output_csv
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def upload
  result(params[:csv])
end

def result(fpath=params[:file_path])
  output_csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    CSV.foreach(fpath, headers: true) do |row|
      csv << row
    end
  end

  # Download the file into user's computer
  send_data output_csv
end
```